# Why is the plural acronym "CSS" treated as singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms, internet, programming

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets, which is a plural phrase. One would say:

> Cascading Style Sheets *are* used to provide a central location for all of the stylings of a project.

However, it seems to be the prevalent usage to say:

> CSS *is* used to provide a central location for all of the stylings of a project.

Why do we do this, and is this correct? Would anyone ever say "CSS *are* used to provide a central location for all of the stylings of a project"?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/how-to-treat-a-country-name-that-has-a-plural-meaning

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CSS here has evolved as a noun independent as to what it means as an acronym. It refers not just to "cascading style sheets" themselves, but to the entire system and infrastructure for styling web pages.

In short, it is a singular noun that has come into existence due to common use.

Here is a similar example: Imagine a company called "Unlimited Designs." judging by the name, you might say something like "Unlimited Designs is going out of business." It's a singular noun, even though designs is plural.

Comment: Of course, in British English, they would say "Unlimited Designs are going out of business"

Comment: @nohat Why is that, out of curiosity?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Formal_and_notional_agreement

Comment: @nohat That actually says "Proper nouns that are plural in form take a plural verb in both AmE and BrE."

Comment: @Arda Xi, it does say that, and it's wrong. United States is not the only exception. There are many cases where plural-in-form proper nouns take singular verbs.

Comment: Great answer.
An example i would use to show how it makes sense is:
"The CSS language is well received" If you read out the acronym you will probably say Cascading Style Sheet, without the plural, because there is no need for it when describing it as a language.
The problem is CSS allows for and is most often used with many files, or sheets, so when a website uses CSS it uses many CSS. [See what i did there with the last phrase ;)]

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell I wouldn't refer to CSS as a 'language', CSS is an aspect or feature of HTML, not a separate language in its own right.

Answer (score 6):

First, according to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/), “Cascading Style Sheets” or “CSS” is the name of a specific language, and therefore there is nothing wrong with treating them as singular.

Second, people sometimes refer to a style sheet written in CSS as “cascading style sheet” (for an obvious reason), although this usage does not appear in the spec if I am not mistaken.  In your example

> Cascading Style Sheets are used to provide a central location for all of the stylings of a project

“Cascading Style Sheets” is used in this meaning, and therefore it is plural.

Answer (score 2):

In general popular acronyms, with time, tend to be used as independent words without always thinking to their original expanded form. This doesn't only result in mismatched singular/plural forms, but also in other humorous inconsistencies, such as the [RAS Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome) (a.k.a. Redundant Acronym Syndrome Syndrome).

Comment: I've definitely caught myself talking about CSS sheets, pin numbers, and atm machines.